# Express creating 404 error on non-index route with nginx proxy but not on local

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I have an express server that handles my routing and am using nginx to proxy my requests. However, when accessing a route that is not `'/'`, I receive a 404 error from express. I've looked at a lot of other answers so far and they all seem to be 404s from nginx and are resolved by removing `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;`, but that's not the case for me. I also see a lot of questions about 404-ing for static files with express/nginx, but I don't think that's necessarily the case here. Rather, I'm unsure how my situation relates to those questions since I'm templating through pug with express.

The error I get is:

```
NotFoundError: Not Found
    at /root/my-app/app.js:27:10
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/root/my-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/root/my-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /root/my-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/root/my-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/root/my-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /root/my-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15
    at next (/root/my-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:260:14)
    at Function.handle (/root/my-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/root/my-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
```

which is triggered by (in app.js):

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    next(createError(404));
});
```

My router looks like:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');                        // does not give me 404 error
});

router.get('/other-route', (req, res) => {
    res.render('other-route-pug-file');         // gives me 404 error
});
```

My nginx config looks like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://example.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    # ssl config details

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; # the port that my express server is listening to
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

So this error only shows up when I route my app through nginx into my domain. On localhost I can see `/other-route` fine. I'm also just unsure how I can go about debugging something like this since I can't really `console.log()` to somewhere easily and I'm pretty new to proxying through nginx, so any help in either area/solving this is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem. I am using an inefficient method to sync my code on the server and github. I did not `yarn install` in my directory after I cloned it the since the first time. I don't know why I didn't just pull inside my directory on the server. I'm not necessarily sure why other parts of my project were working, but that fixed it for me. Thanks for the help!